# 20.04.2 won't boot after linux-image-5.11.0-22-generic:amd64 got auto installed

Tags: boot, 20.04, kernel

on June 23rd 2021, these packages were suggested and installed. Taken from the `grep " install " /var/log/dpkg.log.1`

```
2021-06-23 06:44:09 install linux-modules-5.8.0-59-generic:amd64 <none> 5.8.0-59.66\~20.04.1  
2021-06-23 06:44:10 install linux-image-5.8.0-59-generic:amd64 <none> 5.8.0-59.66\~20.04.1  
2021-06-23 06:44:10 install linux-modules-extra-5.8.0-59-generic:amd64 <none> 5.8.0-59.66\~20.04.1  
2021-06-23 06:44:13 install linux-hwe-5.8-headers-5.8.0-59:all <none> 5.8.0-59.66\~20.04.1  
2021-06-23 06:44:16 install linux-headers-5.8.0-59-generic:amd64 <none> 5.8.0-59.66\~20.04.1  
2021-06-23 06:45:04 install linux-modules-5.11.0-22-generic:amd64 <none> 5.11.0-22.23\~20.04.1  
2021-06-23 06:45:05 install linux-image-5.11.0-22-generic:amd64 <none> 5.11.0-22.23\~20.04.1  
2021-06-23 06:45:05 install linux-signatures-nvidia-5.11.0-22-generic:amd64 <none> 5.11.0-22.23\~20.04.1+1  
2021-06-23 06:45:05 install linux-objects-nvidia-460-5.11.0-22-generic:amd64 <none> 5.11.0-22.23\~20.04.1+1  
2021-06-23 06:45:06 install linux-modules-nvidia-460-5.11.0-22-generic:amd64 <none> 5.11.0-22.23\~20.04.1+1
```

Here is what is in my grub config `awk -F\\' '/menuentry / {print $2}' /boot/grub/grub.cfg`:

```
Ubuntu  
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-22-generic  
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.11.0-22-generic (recovery mode)  
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-59-generic  
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-59-generic (recovery mode)  
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-55-generic  
Ubuntu, with Linux 5.8.0-55-generic (recovery mode)  
UEFI Firmware Settings
```

As suggested, here is my `apt-cache policy` results:

```
Package files:
 100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     release a=now
 500 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main all Packages
     release o=yarn,a=stable,n=stable,l=yarn-stable,c=main,b=all
     origin dl.yarnpkg.com
 500 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main i386 Packages
     release o=yarn,a=stable,n=stable,l=yarn-stable,c=main,b=i386
     origin dl.yarnpkg.com
 500 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=yarn,a=stable,n=stable,l=yarn-stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.yarnpkg.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-y-ppa-manager,a=focal,n=focal,l=Y PPA Manager,c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/y-ppa-manager/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-webupd8team-y-ppa-manager,a=focal,n=focal,l=Y PPA Manager,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main armhf Packages
     release o=code stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=code stable,c=main,b=armhf
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main arm64 Packages
     release o=code stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=code stable,c=main,b=arm64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=code stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=code stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/ms-teams stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=ms-teams stable,a=stable,n=stable,l=ms-teams stable,c=main,b=amd64
     origin packages.microsoft.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-releases/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-stebbins-handbrake-releases,a=focal,n=focal,l=HandBrake Releases,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages
     release v=0.4,o=Spotify LTD,a=stable,n=stable,l=Spotify Public Repository,c=non-free,b=i386
     origin repository.spotify.com
 500 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
     release v=0.4,o=Spotify LTD,a=stable,n=stable,l=Spotify Public Repository,c=non-free,b=amd64
     origin repository.spotify.com
 500 https://updates.signal.org/desktop/apt xenial/main amd64 Packages
     release o=. xenial,a=xenial,n=xenial,l=. xenial,c=main,b=amd64
     origin updates.signal.org
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-obsproject-obs-studio,a=focal,n=focal,l=OBS Studio,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_12.x focal/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Node Source,n=focal,l=Node Source,c=main,b=amd64
     origin deb.nodesource.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/mixxx/mixxx/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-mixxx-mixxx,a=focal,n=focal,l=Mixxx Releases,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://cli-assets.heroku.com/apt ./ Packages
     release o=Heroku,a=stable,c=
     origin cli-assets.heroku.com
 500 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
     release v=1.0,o=Google LLC,a=stable,n=stable,l=Google,c=main,b=amd64
     origin dl.google.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-ethereum-ethereum,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ethereum (Release builds),c=main,b=i386
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ethereum/ethereum/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-ethereum-ethereum,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ethereum (Release builds),c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://download.cudo.org/repo/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Cudo,a=stable,n=stable,l=Cudo,c=main,b=amd64
     origin download.cudo.org
 500 https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable/main amd64 Packages
     release o=Brave Software,a=stable,n=stable,l=Brave Browser,c=main,b=amd64
     origin brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/atareao/telegram/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-atareao-telegram,a=focal,n=focal,l=Telegram,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/appimagelauncher-team/stable/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=LP-PPA-appimagelauncher-team-stable,a=focal,n=focal,l=AppImageLauncher - Stable PPA - Official Releases,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ppa.launchpad.net
 500 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal/stable amd64 Packages
     release o=Docker,a=focal,l=Docker CE,c=stable,b=amd64
     origin download.docker.com
 500 https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal-rc/main i386 Packages
     release o=ubuntu focal-rc,a=focal-rc,n=focal-rc,l=ubuntu focal-rc,c=main,b=i386
     origin apt.kitware.com
 500 https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal-rc/main amd64 Packages
     release o=ubuntu focal-rc,a=focal-rc,n=focal-rc,l=ubuntu focal-rc,c=main,b=amd64
     origin apt.kitware.com
 500 https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release o=ubuntu focal,a=focal,n=focal,l=ubuntu focal,c=main,b=i386
     origin apt.kitware.com
 500 https://apt.kitware.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release o=ubuntu focal,a=focal,n=focal,l=ubuntu focal,c=main,b=amd64
     origin apt.kitware.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-security,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin security.ubuntu.com
 100 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 100 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-backports,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal-updates,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=i386
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/multiverse amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=multiverse,b=amd64
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=i386
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/universe amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=universe,b=amd64
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=i386
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/restricted amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=restricted,b=amd64
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main i386 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=i386
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
 500 http://ca.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
     release v=20.04,o=Ubuntu,a=focal,n=focal,l=Ubuntu,c=main,b=amd64
     origin ca.archive.ubuntu.com
```

The 5.11.0.-22 does not boot. I really would like to know how to find what's missing for it to work.

Any tools or tips to find out?

Comment: What OS & release are you using?   Ubuntu 20.04 LTS using the HWE kernel is still on the 5.8 kernel, as 5.11 is still in *testing* for 20.04.  Are you using Pop OS or another OS & thus the *testing* software?  as Ubuntu doesn't yet have 5.11 (due on 20.04.3; current is still 20.042)  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&arch=any&searchon=names&keywords=linux-generic-hwe-20.04

Comment: If you purpose is QA-testing, then thank you, however this site recommends you file bugs so issues can be fixed before they reach end-users.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ReportingBugs   Thank you for helping make Ubuntu better.

Comment: I'm not doing any QA, I need a stable system, so this is a bug it seems.  I need to know why this occured.

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release: 20.04
Codename: focal
```

Comment: If you're using 20.04 and want a stable system, then I'd check your sources, as you're not using the *stable* HWE kernel, but a *testing* (5.11) kernel currently still in QA before it reaches end-users (who are still on 5.8).  Pop OS however uses the 5.11 kernel which is why I mentioned it (they use *testing* willing to accept glitches more readily to get newer features for newer hardware faster). I would look where it's from (`apt-cache policy`) and check your sources as *stable* 20.04.2 uses 5.8 kernel still.  Your system has been opened up for -proposed or still in QA software I'm betting.

Comment: Even -proposed for *focal* still has 5.8.0-61.generic, 5.4.0-79 & older kernels available for *focal*, so check your sources (if not obvious there, then apt logs) as you're using a (a) manually installed *testing* kernel, (b) not using Ubuntu 20.04, or (c) have corrupted your sources (5.11 is used by *hirsute* or 21.04 and not 20.04; at least not yet - that will occur at 20.04.3)

Comment: So @guiverc with that apt-cache policy list, am I not on the stable tree?

Comment: @guiverc Ubuntu is littered with broken kernels all over their kernel farm lately. I wouldn't worry about it and simply use the versions that do install and work correctly. I'm on LTS `4.14` Ubuntu kernel chain and the last good one was around `4.14.216`. I periodically check in for newer kernels but they all failed to grow on the Ubuntu kernel farm (for AMD64 at least). I'll just stick with it forever I guess because upgrading is a pain in the butt anyway. I emailed one Ubuntu Kernel team member who fixed the Ubuntu Mainline Kernel farm once before but this time he didn't respond.

Answer (score 2):

I have the same problem after doing the recommended update.  I also run the 20.04.2 LTS OS and as I am a newbee, I don't experiment with the kernel or system. The recommended update went through then it won't boot up.  My workaround is to use the Grub troubleshooting option and to select the previous 5.8 kernel and the system works normally.

Comment: Booting to the previous kernel version is a God send sometimes. Make sure you pin that kernel version so you don't accidentally loose it.

Comment: Beware, if you re-install the nvidia meta package from the command line in the newer kernel it may impact the previous kernel as well. You may then also be able to fall back to any discrete graphics by purging the nvidia driver until there is a fix for this.